# NetSuite Rest Web Services Query Last Update

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite Rest WebServices, we can define multiple integrations and each one has a different Application ID (a Guid value).
is there any way to query salesOrders (or any other records) created by a specific Integration?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what platform you are using.  But, in the past, I've done just the opposite of that (pulling records not created by a specific user), using the createdby field.  You can do it via saved searches in most integration platforms, and some allow you to do it via a normal NetSuite query.  Hope that helps some...?